# Using arrays or bytes to set multiple outputs in Structured Text

Tags: automation, plc, st, twincat

I am fooling around in TwinCAT3 trying and getting familiar with ST. I now have a simple question.

Say I have 8 LEDS. Each assigned to an output 1-8. Now I want to be able to send in a byte looking like such: 10101010. Lets call that variable to hold that byte setOUTPUTS. **Would I initalize setOUTPUTS as follows to hold that?**

```
bsetOUTPUTS := BYTE;
```

**After I initialize that variable, how could I loop through it to set each LED to the corresponding bit?**

*For instance: setOUTPUTS = 10001000, how would i loop through setOUTPUTS variable to set LED 8 and LED 4 ON , while leaving the others OFF.*

IF this is not possible, what is the alternative way using arrays?

Thanks!!

Comment: are you programming in Codesys?

Comment: No in TwinCAT environment

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a byte you would

```
setOUTPUTS : BYTE:=86; (* equiavlent to 01010101  *)
```

you can set the outputs based on a bit as follows

```
out1 := setOUTPUTS.0;  (* bit 0 of byte *)
out2:=setOUTPUTS.1;  (* bit 1 of byte *)
```

you might think that you could do something like to loop through the bits in the byte

```
FOR i:=0 TO 8 BY 1 DO
(* out is an array of outputs *)
out[i] := setOUTPUTS.i;
END_FOR
```

but unfortunately you are unable to do this.  As far as I know setting them individually is the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare each bit of your setOutputs variable with a bit that is shifted through the length of setOutputs:

```
FOR i := 0 TO 7 DO
  out[i] := setOutputs AND SHL(1, i);
END_FOR;
```

Comment: Good answer.  I didn't think about that.  +1 for you.

Comment: Would out[i] be the array/enum of 8 LEDS? and does SHL mean shift-left by 1? Thanks!

Comment: out[i] is an array that could be mapped to 8 individual LEDs.
SHL(n,i) will shift the number n, 'i' times to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply map the bit of "bsetOUTPUTS" to the IO.

[image]

Offset 0 means bit 0, offset 1 means bit 1, etc.

So I will link my channel 1 (LED 1) to bsetOUTPUTS offset 0, channel 2 to bsetOUTPUTS offset 1, etc.

[image]